# What is the verb for extinguishing the candle flame with your fingers?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs, phrasal-verbs

If I have a candle which is lightning and I want to stop it by my touching the wick and stop it mechanically by my fingers at the moment because I want to sleep. Do I want to **extinguish** it, or to **put** it **out**, or to **blow** it **out**?

What verb usually describes this action in the spoken English?

Comment: Snuff out seems the most idiomatic phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your fingers you are not *blowing it out*. *Extinguish* or *put out* are both OK (the first is a bit more formal). If you are actually pinching the wick between finger and thumb you could even say you are *pinching it out*

Incidentally, *lightning* is what comes with thunder. A burning candle is *alight*.